# Problems in connecting to MusicBrainz database using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, musicbrainz

I am trying to connect to the MusicBrainz database using the psycopg2 python's module. I have followed the instructions presented on http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Server/Setup, but I cannot succeed in connecting. In particular I am using the following little script:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect( database = 'musicbrainz_db', user= 'musicbrainz', password = 'musicbrainz', port = 5000, host='10.16.65.250')
print "Connection Estabilished"
```

The problem is that when I launch it, it never reaches the print statement, and the console (I'm on linux) is block indefinitely. It does not even catches the ctrl-c kill, so I have to kill python itself in another console. What can cause this?

Comment: do u have an AV that may be blocking access?

Comment: Are you able to ping your Musicbrainz server from a separate command prompt?

Comment: @Talvalin Yes, I can ping the server.

Comment: @PurityLake the database is hosted on a pre-made virtual machine, so I suppose not, but I am not sure of it

Comment: not familiar with musicbrainz, if u don't get an answer here perhaps try a dedicated forum perhaps?

Comment: @PurityLake, I have not yet tried a dedicated forums because I thought it was an error more related to the database in general (it should be a Postgresql one), than to the musicbrainz in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mistaking MusicBrainz-Server to be only the database.
What's running on port 5000 is the Web Server.
You can access `http://10.16.65.250:5000` in the browser.

Postgres is also running, but listens on `localhost:5432`.
This works:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="musicbrainz_db",
                        user="musicbrainz", password="musicbrainz",
                        port="5432", host="localhost")
print("Connection established")
```

In order to make postgres listen to more than localhost you need to change `listen_addresses` in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgres.conf` and make an entry for your (client) host or network in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`.

My VM is running in a 192.168.1.0/24 network so I set `listen_addresses='*'` in postgres.conf and in pg_hab.conf:

```
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          trust
```

I can now connect from my local network to the DB in the VM.

---

Depending on what you actually need, you might not want to connect to the MusicBrainz Server via postgres. There is a [MusicBrainz web service](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2) you can access in the VM.
Example:
`http://10.16.65.250:5000/ws/2/artist/c5c2ea1c-4bde-4f4d-bd0b-47b200bf99d6`.
In that case you might be interested in a library to process the data:
[python-musicbrainzngs](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/).

EDIT:
You need to set `musicbrainzngs.set_hostname("10.16.65.250:5000")` for musicbrainzngs to connect to your local VM.

Comment: I can reproduce psycopg2 blocking when trying port 5000. This doesn't work since 5000 runs the HTTP protocol, but psycopg2 shouldn't be blocking, but rather give an exception.

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thank you very much! Regarding the MusicBrainz web service, it seems that the library python-musicbrainz-ngs connects only to the "main" musicbrainz web service and I don't know if I can redirected to the local one. In fact, the main database has a limitation of one web service call per second and, in my case, this would not be enough.

Comment: Please have a look at [musicbrainzngs.set_hostname()](https://python-musicbrainz-ngs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#musicbrainzngs.set_hostname). You can also connect to a local MusicBrainz Server.

Comment: FYI: I get OperationalError after ca. 10 minutes when trying to access port 5000 with psycopg2.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In any case I think I will stick to the database because it seems that the library still does not have api functions for retrieving lyrics and relationships. Right now I have a mismatch between the musicbrainz identifier and the name of the artist but I've already asked a question on the musicbrainz forum.

Comment: Lyrics are not on musicbrainz.org at all and relationships are given when you use the right includes: http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/c5c2ea1c-4bde-4f4d-bd0b-47b200bf99d6?inc=artist-rels. I wouldn't recommend using the DB directly at all.

Comment: Sorry, I did not meant lyrics. I want to retrieve the name of their songs. I know that the relationships are retrievable from the web service, but I don't know how to query it without using the library that seems to not have included this functionality yet. I am not an expert in python or web services, so I would need something already done.

Comment: Please invest a bit of time to get to know musicbrainzngs. The lib *does* support giving song names and relationships! I will continue the discussion in the forums: http://forums.musicbrainz.org/viewtopic.php?id=4233